# How to get filepath of oppend file on tab

Tags: java, tabs, filepath

Open a file -> Tab created(tab's name is file's name) -> append on text area by using file path.

The order is like this. What I can't figure out is If I opened 2 ~ more files. Is there any way to get file path of file that opened & appended in tab where I focus on now?